# Increase Accuracy on Keras Multiclass Classifier

Tags: python, classification, keras, multiclass-classification, python-3.x

I have a dataset with the shape (430, 17). My output is a single column consisting of possible options "Best", "Medium", "Worst". I split my data into `X` and `y`, and then into training and testing sets after using the `StandardScaler` to scale X.

I then using the `LabelEncoder` and `get_dummies` to prepare my output values.

```
>>>X_train[:1]

   array([[-0.62115527,  0.73646208,  1.27931666, -1.13977066, -0.03124594,
        -0.06595102, -0.35812162,  2.47947661,  0.01705523, -0.75215293,
        -0.43173137, -0.15181261]])

>>>y_train[:1]

   array([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

I then prepared a keras Model based on an [example from the iris dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/lavajiit/deep-learning-iris-dataset-keras) that also worked with a multiclass classifier using Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim = 17 , activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.04),'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

I have been changing the inputs and general architecture of the model for the last few hours, but I cannot seem to be able to get the accuracy above 63.64%.

Sample Output:

```
Epoch 95/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6250 - accuracy: 0.7037
Epoch 96/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7214 - accuracy: 0.6980
Epoch 97/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7595 - accuracy: 0.7123
Epoch 98/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7197 - accuracy: 0.6838
Epoch 99/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6658 - accuracy: 0.6895
Epoch 100/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.7103 - accuracy: 0.6838
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 0.8703 - accuracy: 0.6364
```

My question is:

Can you advise on what I can do to increase the accuracy of the validation data?

**Edit 1:**

Changed the hidden layer nodes to 12, and changed to activate to relu. Here is a picture of the training and validation so far:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Changed the focus of the posting from two questions to one. I also added the most recent model, and results:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim = 17 , activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(24, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(24, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.11))
model.add(Dense(24, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.002),loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', "mse", "mae"])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 800, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0)
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Change *tanh* to *ReLU*. 2. Model is too big for 400 records, change each layer to ~10-12 Nodes and comment on what is the result with these changes

Comment: @10xAI Thanks! I changed to ReLU, and made each layer 12 nodes. model.evaluate(X_test, y_test) is now 73.86%. If I run in multiple times, it fluctuates from 65% to 73%. How did you know to decrease the nodes? And what can we do to improve the accuracy?

Comment: Could you plot the accuracy and the loss during the learning phase?

Comment: @sentence I added it above :)

Comment: You should plot accuracy for both training and validation on the same graph. And loss for both training and validation on the same graph. Moreover, please provide the dimension for training set and validation set. And the number of samples per class for training set and validation set. Thanks.

Comment: Your question needs more focus (and it may be temporaly close for it!). First there is no need to explain why you separated it into 3 classes, just say that you have a dataset of 430 entries with 12 features for each and you have 3 classes period. That eliminates your pre processing question (question 1), if you want to ask it anyway, create a new question.

Comment: Please edit the question to be a single coherent question.  The **EDIT** headers are distracting. Anybody who is interested can see the edits here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/posts/77619/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You should understand if the model you built is able to learn from the data. Therefore, plot the accuracy and the loss for both training and validation set versus the number of epochs.

Then, if the model needs more epochs, give it more epochs. Otherwise, try different optimizers, activation functions, number of neurons, number of layers, and batch size.

---

From the (flawed) plots you provided (please, plot accuracy for training and validation on one graph, and loss for training and validation on another graph), you can see two clear phenomena:

1. accuracy stops to increase after a very few epochs;
2. loss curve is unstable.

which suggest that the model does not learn from the data (I would start off with a shallow architecture, tuning number of neurons, trying different optimizers, activation functions, and then number of layers) and the dataset could be unrepresentative.